# Rectangles Approximation of a function over a certain interval.

Tags: calculus

So basically I'm doing Rectangles Approximation.

I have the function $f(x) = x^3 + 1 $

and I need to calculate $R_{50}$ for $f$ on [0,2]

I found $\Delta x$ which is $\frac{1}{25}$

$N$ = $50$

I found $x_0$ through $x_{50}$

${x_k}$ = {0,$\frac{1}{25}$ , $\frac{2}{25}$, $\frac{3}{25}$, ... 2}

Now I want to know if there's a easier way to calculate the rectangle Approximation. Instead of calculating each number.

This is the formula:

$$R_N = \Delta x\sum_{j=1}^n f(x_j) $$

Any help is appericated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is! By the way, $0$ is not one of the $x_j$s.

$$ \sum_{j=1}^n f(x_j) = \sum_{j=1}^n f\left( \frac{2j}{n} \right) = \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \frac{2j}{n} \right)^3 + 1
$$
Using [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula),
$$ \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \frac{2j}{n} \right)^3 = \frac{8}{n^3} \sum_{j=1}^n j^3 = \frac{8}{n^3} \frac{n^4 + 2n^3 + n^2}{4} = \frac{2n^2 + 4n + 2}{n}
$$
Subtituting back,
$$ R_n = \Delta x \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \left(\frac{2j}{n} \right)^3 + 1\right) = \Delta x \left(\frac{2n^2 + 4n + 2}{n} + n \right)
$$
Now you can plug in $n = 50$ to obtain the desired result.

Comment: Haven't learned Faulhaber's formula yet, but I'm guessing I just sub it 50 for N and Ill get the final answer?

Comment: @shawnedward You will have to subtitute it into the equation $R_n = \Delta x^{-1} \sum_{j=1}^n f(j)$ and plug in $n =50$.

Comment: Hmm, now I just got confused, I dont sub in N for the last fraction the $2n^2 + 4n...$ thing.

Comment: @shawnedward I've edited to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks but isn't the $+n$ in the bracket after the fraction suppose to be $+1$ instead?

Comment: @shawnedward $+1$ is inside the summation, so it becomes $+n$ when $n$ copies are summed.

Comment: alright thanks!

Comment: I get 6.1 as the answer, isn't it suppose to be 9? Since $x_{50}$ is 2 , s if you sub that in you will get 9 in the original function.

Comment: @shawnedward I don't know whether my algebra is correct or not. I'm just showing how to do it.